# Call function from different file context of undefined

Tags: node.js

I am able to call the function from a different file, but for some reason my conversationPayload.context does not get passed.

Im using the middleware bot, for Watson but this is what I have so far.

file 1  :

```
  middleware.before = function(message, conversationPayload, callback) {
    var common = require('./tools/toneAnalyzer');
    queryInput = conversationPayload.input.text
    common.func1(queryInput);
 };
```

file2

```
module.exports = {

    func1: function (queryInput,conversationPayload) {
    console.log('fink1!!!!! ' + queryInput);
     var toneParams = {
      tone_input: { 'text': queryInput },
      content_type: 'application/json'
    };

    toneAnalyzer.tone(toneParams, function (err, tone) {
      let toneScore = ''
      let toneJoy = ''
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else { 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tone, null, 2));
        const emotionTones = tone.document_tone.tones;

        const len = emotionTones.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (emotionTones[i].tone_id === 'anger') {
          console.log('Input = ', queryInput )
          console.log('emotion_id = ', 'Emotion_id', emotionTones[i].tone_id);
          toneScore = emotionTones[i].tone_id;
          console.log(toneScore + ' =  toneScore')
          break;
        }else if(emotionTones[i].tone_id === 'joy'){
          toneJoy = emotionTones[i].tone_id;
        }
      }

    }if (conversationPayload.context) {
    conversationPayload.context['tone_anger'] = toneScore
    conversationPayload.context['tone_joy'] = toneJoy    
    }
    callback(null, conversationPayload);

      });
    }
```

The script runs smooth until i get to the code if (conversationPayload.context)...
that where I get **TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of undefined**

This works flawless if I have everything in file 1. 
I have experimented around a bit with moving the messages, callback and conversationPayload params. but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: somehow conversationPayload is undefined. Context is not available in conversationPayload. That is why "TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of undefined"

Check conversationPayload is undefined or not then check conversationPayload.context

Comment: Doesn't `func1` recieve 2 parameters?

Comment: @SohamKrishnaPaul guess i was to fast for helping, you where correct. will post solution

Answer (score 0):

I case anybody is trying to do similar things.
the solution was to send the 2 parameters conversationPayload and callback

```
module.exports = {

    func1: function (queryInput,conversationPayload,callback) {
    console.log('fink1!!!!! ' + queryInput);
     var toneParams = {
      tone_input: { 'text': queryInput },
      content_type: 'application/json'
    };

    toneAnalyzer.tone(toneParams, function (err, tone) {
      let toneScore = ''
      let toneJoy = ''
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else { 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tone, null, 2));
        const emotionTones = tone.document_tone.tones;

        const len = emotionTones.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (emotionTones[i].tone_id === 'anger') {
          console.log('Input = ', queryInput )
          console.log('emotion_id = ', 'Emotion_id', emotionTones[i].tone_id);
          toneScore = emotionTones[i].tone_id;
          console.log(toneScore + ' =  toneScore')
          break;
        }else if(emotionTones[i].tone_id === 'joy'){
          toneJoy = emotionTones[i].tone_id;
        }
      }

    }if (conversationPayload.context) {
    conversationPayload.context['tone_anger'] = toneScore
    conversationPayload.context['tone_joy'] = toneJoy    
    }
    callback(null, conversationPayload);

      });


    }
```